# How to update Lagom to latest stable release version

Tags: lagom

I followed the following tutorial: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/java/GettingStartedMaven.html

Point 3 mentioned:

> Enter the number that corresponds with
>   com.lightbend.lagom:maven-archetype-lagom-java (at time of writing,
>   the number 1, and the only one available). Maven prompts you for the
>   version.

The problem is that Maven did not prompt me for a version, and used 1.1.0-RC1 by default. This version builds properly, although there are also minor errors popping up in the standard out like the one here:

[image]

Point 4 mentions:

> Enter the number corresponding with the version of Lagom you want to
>   use. We recommend using the current stable release).

Current stable release version is 1.4.6.
I've tried modifying my Maven pom.xml manually since I didn't receive the prompt and tried rebuilding:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <lagom.version>1.4.6</lagom.version> <!-- Changed here -->
    <play.version>2.5.4</play.version>
    <conductr.lib.name>lagom10-conductr-bundle-lib_2.11</conductr.lib.name>
</properties>
```

But building with `lagom:runAll`results in error:

[image]

1.4.6 should be a stable release. Are there dependencies that also require updates that I have to take care of when using this version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I followed the following tutorial and it works fine:

https://www.lagomframework.com/blog/introducing-maven-support.html